# C++ MFC : Debug Assertion error when trying to call method using instance of a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have this function in test2.cpp

```
void Ctest2App::message(){
    MessageBox(0, L"And text here", L"MessageBox caption", MB_OK);

}
```

I call it from test2Dlg in the following way

```
void Ctest2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    Ctest2App t;
    t.message();
}
```

When I press the button I get a Debug Assertion error. why?

the test2.cpp file-

```
// test2.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test2.h"
#include "test2Dlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// Ctest2App

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Ctest2App, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Ctest2App construction

Ctest2App::Ctest2App()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only Ctest2App object

Ctest2App theApp;


// Ctest2App initialization

BOOL Ctest2App::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();


    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // Create the shell manager, in case the dialog contains
    // any shell tree view or shell list view controls.
    CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    Ctest2Dlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

    // Delete the shell manager created above.
    if (pShellManager != NULL)
    {
        delete pShellManager;
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}

void Ctest2App::message(){
    MessageBox(0, L"And text here", L"MessageBox caption", MB_OK);

}
```

Comment: It surely has something to do with `Ctest2App`, because the call to `MessageBox` seems ok. What is `Ctest2App`?

Comment: Its a newly created Dialog based MFC Project. There is nothing on it except the constructor, object and InitInstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have attempted to create a second Ctest2App object, but there can only be one in an app. MFC provides a global function to access the already-created app object:

```
AfxGetApp()->message();
```